# watch a variable using observable in angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a variable called `loading` ( and it's `false` in the beginning and it is a boolean variable ) and a button which its text depend on that variable.

I wrote a method to do that for me like this:

```
changeBtnTxt() {
  this.loginBtn = this.loading ? 'please wait':'login';
}
```

now, I want to know how can I watch that variable changing to fire this method using a `RxJS` Observable.

this is my component

```
export class LoginFormComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  loading = false;
  loginBtn = 'ورود';
  loginModel: LoginFormModel = new LoginFormModel();

  @ViewChild('loginForm') form: any;

  constructor(private service: LoginFormService,
    private basicView: BasicViewService) {}  // inject services to our component

  ngOnInit() {}

  login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.changeBtnTxt(); // I want to remove this line and do the changes just by above code
    this.service.loginModel = this.loginModel;
    this.service.doLogin() // returns a Http get Observable
      .subscribe(
        res => {
        },
        msg => {
          if (msg.status !== 401) {
            this.loading = false; // want back to normal without call changeBtnTxt()
          }
        });
    this.form.reset();
  }

  changeBtnTxt() {
    this.loginBtn = this.loading ? 'ورود' : 'لطفا صبر کنید';
  }
}
```

and here its html

```
<form novalidate #loginForm="ngForm" (submit)="login()">
  <div class="ibox-title">
    <h2 class="font-bold">ورود به حساب کاربری</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="ibox-content" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="نام کاربری" 
        name="username"
        [(ngModel)]="loginModel.username"
        required
        #username="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:0px">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" 
        placeholder="رمزعبور"
        name="password"
        [(ngModel)]="loginModel.password"
        required
        #password="ngModel">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="ibox-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b"
      [disabled]="loginForm.invalid || loading" [value]="loginBtn"/>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" (click)="showHelp()">راهنما</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: is `loading` of type observable? then you can `subscribe` to it? where is `loading` coming from? is it an input?

Comment: @SergioAlen no, as I meantioned it is false, so it's boolean

Comment: ok so what's triggering this method `changeBtnTxt()` and where is `loading` changing

Comment: actually, it is the question itself, I don't know how to bind this method. right now I have to call it manually right after every time I change the `loading` value from true to false and vice-versa

Comment: maybe use a lifecycle method like `ngOnChanges` so replace `changeBtnTxt()` with `ngOnChanges()`, it's hard without seeing the whole code

Comment: Hi @SeyedAliRoshan can you publish your controller and template please?

Comment: Hi, I'm actually on it right now and publish them soon

Comment: This sounds like it could be solved with a simple template binding: `<button>{{ loading ? 'please wait' : 'login' }}</button>` Using an observable to watch the value seems extremely over-the-top.

Comment: @SimonK you are right but the main point besides of changing that input text is that I want to know how can I watch variable is getting changed and do something then

Comment: You cannot watch a variable in this way using Angular 2+. The closest you can get is the answer I posted which doesn't use Observables. Unless you variable is an `@Input`, of course, and then the comment from @SergioAlen is the way to go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea, you could use getter and setter methods and not have to use an observable at all:

```
private _loading: boolean = false;

public get loading(): boolean {
    return this._loading;
}

public set loading(isLoading: boolean) {
    this._loading = isLoading;
    this.changeBtnTxt();
}
```

And then you just use `loading` like a normal variable:

```
this.loading = true;
```

Comment: OPs question is specific about using observables

Comment: It cannot be done using observables as there is no way to watch the specific value of a variable and changing the value using a call to a `Subject.next()` is no better than just calling a method to change the value!

Answer (score 5):

You could use Subject and subscribe to the observable in the constructor... then add a simple function to emit the change with next... like this:

```
  public myObservable = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() {
    this.myObservable.subscribe(val => {
      this.loading = val;
      this.loginBtn = 'loged in';
      alert(this.loading)
    })
  }

  changeBtnTxt() {
    this.loginBtn = 'please wait';
    setTimeout(() => { // Only for demonstration purpose
      const val = (this.loading == true ? false : true);
      this.myObservable.next(val);
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Check the [working example in stakblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-observable?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)